# how to use google play service in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm working at my new mobile game. The work is going well but when I tried to use google play services at the game, it didn't work by several reasons that I couldn't understand.

There are many guides about using google play service, but still they are all scattered. So I can't totally understand about this.

Could you help me to how to use google play service step by step?

Or link that can solve my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not remotely an answerable problem. Questions here must be specific and answerable, and requests for guesses and tutorials are generally not productive. What specific problem are you having? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

You may check this [link](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) for Google Play Games plugin for Unity. This plugin allows you to access the Google Play Games API through Unity's [social interface](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Social.html). The plugin provides support for the following features of the Google Play Games API:

> - sign in
> - unlock/reveal/increment achievement
> - post score to leaderboard
> - cloud save read/write
> - show built-in achievement/leaderboards UI
> - events
> - video recording of gameplay
> - [nearby connections](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/NEARBY.md)
> - [turn-based multiplayer](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/TBMP.md)
> - [real-time multiplayer](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/RTMP.md)

To use the plugin, you must first [configure your game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) in the Google Play Developer Console. Follow the instructions on creating a client ID. Be particularly careful when entering your package name and your certificate fingerprints, since mistakes on those screens can be difficult to recover from.

Answer (score 0):

check it

[play-unity-plugins](https://github.com/google/play-unity-plugins)

-play billing
-play instant
-play assets delivery
-anfd so on